# I am getting error "Constructor Dice in Class Dice cannot be applied to given type". Consider that Dice is my class,What does this mean?

Tags: java, variables, random, types, constructor

My problem is that I am getting an error "Constructor [name] in class [name] cannot be applied to given type". I can't make it to my resource center for the class so I can't seek person-to-person aid for this problem. The project is to understand the random class and creating user classes by creating a class called "Dice" which has methods to roll a dice several times as well as to print details and reset the counters. Here is my code for both the class called "Dice" and the file which uses it called "DiceTester":

Dice:

```
/*
    CoinTester.java - tests the Coin class by
    constructing variables and calling it's methods
*/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

  class Dice{

Random rnd=new Random();
    int[] count = new int[6];

    void roll(){
        int a = rnd.nextInt(6);
        count[a]++;
        System.out.print(a+1); 
    }

    void printStats(){
        for(int i=0; i<count.length; i++){
            System.out.println((i+1) + ":" + count[i]);
        }
    }

    void reset(){
        for(int i=0; i<count.length; i++){
            count[i] = 0;
        }
    }

            }
```

DiceTester:

```
    /*
    DiceTester.java - tests the Dice class
    DO NOT MODIFY
*/
public class DiceTester
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    Dice die1 = new Dice(17);
    Dice die2 = new Dice(3);

    // ROLL DICE 20 TIMES PRINT RESULTS

    System.out.println("\nRolling a pair of dice 20 times.");
    for (int i=0 ; i<20 ; ++i)
            System.out.print( die1.roll() + "," +  die2.roll() + "  "); // Each dice equal chance of 1,2,3,4,5 or 6
     System.out.println();

    System.out.println("die1 stats:");
    die1.printStats();
    System.out.println("die2 stats:");
    die2.printStats();

    die1.reset(); // resets all roll counts to 0
    die2.reset(); // resets all roll counts to 0

    // ROLL DICE 20 TIMES PRINT RESULTS

    System.out.println("\nRolling a pair of dice 20 times.");
    for (int i=0 ; i<20 ; ++i)
            System.out.print( die1.roll() + "," +  die2.roll() + "  "); // Each dice equal chance of 1,2,3,4,5 or 6
     System.out.println();

    System.out.println("die1 stats:");
    die1.printStats();
    System.out.println("die2 stats:");
    die2.printStats();

    die1.reset(); // resets all roll counts to 0
    die2.reset(); // resets all roll counts to 0

   }// END main
}//EOF
```

Comment: You're trying to construct a Dice object with an integer as parameter. Your Dice class doesn't contain such a constructor.

Comment: why are you making new Dice(17) with a parameter?

Comment: This may sound horrible but the DiceTester.java file is a starter written entirely by the instructor. I am not able to change that file in any way and so I must work around it. I would not be surprised if there are errors in the starter file as that has happened on several occasions. Now the integer that I am passing, what exactly does it do. For example what would be the difference between the one passing 17 and the one passing 3?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Dice` class you have no constructor. Simply create:

```
class Dice {

  public Dice(int value) {
    // ...
  }

  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `Dice` with `int` argument taking constructor, based on this value you can base `random` calculation:

```
class Dice {
  int max;
  int[] count;

public Dice(int max) {
    count = new int[max];
    this.max = max;
  }

void roll(){
        int a = rnd.nextInt(max);
        count[a]++;
        System.out.print(a+1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what it is this is doing? Is int[] count an array?